# Change color of texture with vertex paint

Tags: texturing, materials, vertex-paint

I have a texture that is grey scale and another with alpha. I used the second images alpha to make parts of the first image transparent. Is there anyway i can affect the color of the grey scale image to use the various colors i have on the vertex painted mesh?

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question?